# Serve a static JSON object file in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, json

How do I serve a static JSON object from a file in rails? (I want to access it in an ajax call)?

What is the best method?

Answer (score 0):

Just place what you want to render in a variable, then use `render :json => variable`
There are sensible defaults for lists, dicts, etc...

See this:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Item: "2.2.8 Rendering JSON"

Comment: Thanks but i want to have the JSON object saved in a file with json syntax and delivered to the client.

Comment: Well, read the contents of the file and then use "render :text".