# How to serve a static JSON file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a file on my server that's outside of my app directory. It's a text file that holds a json object, `/path/to/data.json`.

What's the simplest way to serve this file in Rails, e.g. to return it in response to a GET request?

Here's what I've tried so far, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348712/serve-a-static-json-object-file-in-rails) and others. (This may be way off-base -- I'm new to rails.)

1. added this line to routes.rb
     `resources :data`
2. Wrote the following data_controller.rb

`class DataController < ApplicationController`

```
@data = File.read("/path/to/data.json")

def index
  render :json => @data
 end
end
```

This doesn't work.  When I direct my browser to http://myserver.com/data.json  I just see "null" instead of the `data.json` file.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: if the file format is JSON do you really need to `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode` it if you only intend pass it off as JSON?

Comment: Probably not... let me take that line out and see what happens...

Comment: Hmm.. i doubt it would work anyway, you're still just rendering the `@data`. `@dataJson` is never used.

Comment: In the answer you linked, one of the comments says to just render it as text. Try `render :text @data`

Comment: I tried that, too.  Then I get nothing at all in my browser. :s

Comment: Then I'm guessing that your file path is incorrect. Because you should atleast get the value of `@data` back.  Try rendering `@data = 'test'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this is a scope issue; your outer @data is not the same as the @data in a method.  That is, you can't use instance variables as expected outside of methods because there is no instance yet.

It should work if you use a class variable, eg

```
@@data = File.read("/path/to/data.json")
```

then

```
render :json => @@data
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  That solved the problem.  I hadn't gotten around to learning about variable scope in Rails yet.  I'll get right on that. ;)

Answer (score 10):

Put it in `public/assets/javascripts`. Or `app/assets/javascripts`.  The server may even return the correct content-type.

Comment: Ok, that might be one solution, and it's probably the right way to go once my app goes live.  But for now, while it's still in development, it would be much more convenient for the file to live in a different location, outside of the `public/assets/`.  `data.json` is being accessed by other applications as well as rails, and, for simplicity, I only want to keep one copy of it.

Answer (score 5):

- put `data.json` file into your project directory ( for example `public/data.json`)
- `@data = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/data.json")`
- At last but not least render `:json => @data`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in one line, e.g.

```
render :file => '/path/to/data.json', 
  :content_type => 'application/json',
  :layout => false
```